# "Add to Home Screen", save state without app cache?

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari

I have a web site that I'd like users to be able to add to their home screen. Users will switch between this saved "web app" and a game frequently.

The first problem is that when a user comes back to the saved "web app", it displays the splash screen every time even though it wasn't closed. This is undesirable. Further, when a users clicks on a primary navigation element, it switches the user over to Safari.

How do I get the app to "save state" and not re-load the app when coming back to it (when it hasn't been closed)? How do I get it to load links clicked within the same domain to load within the saved "app" rather than loading them up in Safari?

Safari doesn't reload a page when you switch away from the app and come back, so why does a web site saved to the home screen have to reload when pulled to the front?

I don't want to use an offline database, I don't even need the app to work while offline because it needs to tie to a live database that's constantly changing. Therefore a working offline isn't intuitive because the data would be outdated and irrelevant. Therefore, I don't need cacheing either (except maybe a few resources that don't change often). I just want the darn thing to "save state" and not reload every time the user comes back to it. And links clicked within it, shouldn't take the user out of it unless they are links to a different domain.

I've searched and read and searched and read, but I'm not finding anything other than articles about making a web app work offline. That's not my goal. My goal is to make it behave like Safari does in that if it's not explicitly closed, it keeps it's state.

Comment: I know this is a trivial suggestion, but is it possible to integrate your web app into the iOS app?

Comment: I'm not looking to create an App Store app. I'm just looking to add the web site to the home screen for user convenience as well as the extra screen space that results.

Comment: Alright well I found my way around the link clicks loading externally in Safari by just using Ajax, so that part I think I have worked out. Now to just get it to save state and not reload the view and show the slash screen when returning to the app ...